# Fill nan values in a netcdf file using another netcdf file

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, nco, cdo-climate

I'm trying to fill nan values in a NetCDF file (let's call is 'Target' file) by getting the values from another NetCDf file ('Source' file). [the two example files can be downloaded [from here]](https://gofile.io/?c=wzwu0e)
I was thinking of doing this in python using the following framework:

> Step1- identifying the nan values in the Target file, and extracting
>   the location (lat/long), storing in a dataframe
>
> Step2- Extracting the corresponding values of the stored lat/long from
>   the Source file
>
> Step3- writing these values into the Target file

I came up with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

Source = xr.open_dataset("Source.nc")
Target = xr.open_dataset("Target.nc")

#Step 1 
df = Target.to_dataframe()
df=df.reset_index()
df2=(df.loc[df['ET'].isin([32767,'nan'])])


#Step2
lat = df2["lat"]
lon = df2["lon"]
point_list = zip(lat,lon)

Newdf = pd.DataFrame([])

for i, j in point_list:
    dsloc = Source.sel(lat=i,lon=j,method='nearest')
    DT=dsloc.to_dataframe()
    Newdf=Newdf.append(DT,sort=True)
```

there are three issues with that:
1-  I don’t know how to do step three

2-  The second step take forever to complete as perhaps there are many missing points

3-  This is just for one time step! Using the two files.

So, I believe there might be better ways, easier and faster to do this in python or cdo/Nco…
Any ideas and solutions are welcomed…thank you…
Note that, the two NC files are in different spatial resolution (dimensions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Xarray's `where` method](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html#xarray.DataArray.where) for this. You really want to stay away from a python for loop if you are concerned with efficiency at all. Here's an example of how this would work:

```
# these are the points you want to keep
# you can fine tune this further (exclude values over a threshold)
condition = target.notnull()

# fill the values where condition is false
target_filled = target.where(condition, source)
```

Comment: Thank you... but it returns an error "indexes along dimension 'lat' are not equal" ...perhaps because the two ncfiles have different dimensions

Comment: You'll need to "regrid" or "reindex" source before calling `where()` then.

Comment: I tried aligning them using `a, b = xr.align(source, target, join='right' ,copy=True)` but it returns nan values for my bigger domain !

Comment: You may want to check out xarray's documentation on interpolating data: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/interpolation.html.